# password and confirm password not working on onclick

Tags: javascript

```
    <script>
             var password= document.forms["PestControl"]["password"].value;
             var confirmpassword= document.forms["PestControl"]["confirmpassword"].value;
             function validateForm() {
                 //alert('inside');
              if(!validatePassword()){
                    alert("password did not matched or blank password fields");
                    document.forms["PestControl"]["password"].focus();
                    return false;
                  }
                  else if($.trim(password) != $.trim(confirmpassword)){
                    alert("password did not matched");
                    document.forms["PestControl"]["password"].focus();
                    return true;
                  }

                  else {                 
                     document.PestControl.action = "medical_college_process.php?trans=addcollege";
                     document.PestControl.method = "post";
                     document.PestControl.submit();
                  }
             }
             function validatePassword(){
               var password= document.forms["PestControl"]["password"].value;
               var confirmpassword= document.forms["PestControl"]["confirmpassword"].value;           
               var Exist   =   false;
               if((password.value === '') && (confirm_password.value==='')) {
                 alert();
                 Exist   =   false;
               } 
               else if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
                 Exist   =   false;
               } 
               else {
                 Exist   =   true;
               }
               async:false;
               return Exist;

             }

                 </script>

 <div class="form-group  col-md-12" style="text-align: right;margin-top: 10px;">
                                <label style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Password</label>
                                 <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password"  value="">
                            </div>  

                             <div class="form-group  col-md-12" style="text-align: right;margin-top: 10px;">
                                <label style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Confirm Password </label>
                                 <input id="confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" value="">
                            </div>



                                          <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: right;margin-top: 10px;">
                                             <button type="button" id="button1" name="" onclick="return validateForm()" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">Save</button>
 when i click on save button for password and confirm password i m getting an alert of password did not match or blank password for non-matching password as well as for matching password ...getting same alert message 
when i click on save button for password and confirm password i m getting an alert of password did not match or blank password for non-matching password as well as for matching password ...getting same alert message
```

when i click on save button for password and confirm password i m getting an alert of password did not match or blank password for non-matching password as well as for matching password ...getting same alert message 
    when i click on save button for password and confirm password i m getting an alert of password did not match or blank password for non-matching password as well as for matching password ...getting same alert message

Comment: Can you trim the code down to a working example of where the problem lies?  See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Is it possible to create a fiddle link for your no working code?

Comment: @SumitJha Why a fiddle link?  That's external and SO has it's own code snippet plugin so you can run code here.

Comment: @Archer Thank you. :) That's what I meant.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/172y720s/2/

Comment: @SumitJha https://jsfiddle.net/172y720s/2/

Comment: @Archer https://jsfiddle.net/172y720s/2/

Comment: Please post just the relevant code in the question, not the full code in an external site.  Did you read the link I gave you about how to create a [mcve]?

Comment: I think there is a typo "confirm_password", I think it should be **confirmpassword**. Moreover if  "var password" in Validatepassword is already a string value. So you cannot call again as password.value. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below code. It worked on my side.

```js
function validatePassword(){
  var password= document.forms["PestControl"]["password"];
  var confirmpassword= document.forms["PestControl"]["confirmpassword"];           
  var Exist   =   false;
  if((password.value === '') && (confirmpassword.value==='')) {
    alert('no input');
    Exist   =   false;
  } 
  else if(password.value != confirmpassword.value) {
   alert('wrong password');
   Exist   =   false;
  } 
  else {
    alert('correct');
    Exist   =   true;
  }
  async:false;
  return Exist;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="PestControl">
  User password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
  User confirm password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="confirmpassword">
  <input type="button" value="save" onclick="validatePassword()">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: No problem. Happy helping. Please accept the answer if it worked. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function validatePassword(){
var password= document.getElementById("your pass id").value;
var confirmpassword= document.getElementById("confirm_password").value;                   
 var Exist   =   false;
if((password === '') && (confirmpassword==='')) {
  alert();
  Exist   =   false;
} 
else if(password != confirmpassword) {
  Exist   =   false;
} 
else {
  Exist   =   true;
}
}
```